# How can i show error if user type number in input

Tags: angular, regex, angular-forms

I have template driven form with firstName input.

That input should be requred,have minimum three characters length and should accept only strings.

```
<form class="mt-5" (ngSubmit)="contactUs(f)"  #f="ngForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstName">First Name <span class="error">*</span></label>
                    <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="contactUsForm.firstName" name="firstName" id="firstName"
                        #firstName="ngModel" required minlength="3" 
                        pattern="^[a-zA-Z]" />
                    <div *ngIf="firstName.invalid && (firstName.dirty || firstName.touched)" class="error">
                        <div *ngIf="firstName.errors.required">
                            First Name is required.
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="firstName.errors.minlength">
                            First Name must be at least 3 characters long.
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="firstName.errors.pattern">
                            You can write only letters.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

In my code required and minlength are working. But when i try with pattern
to show to the user that he needs yo write only letters i got stuck.

With this pattern

```
 pattern="^[a-zA-Z]"
```

when i type in my input for example

```
swdsdsdsdsd
```

i get the error - You can write only letters.

but i should not because i typed letters i didn't typed numbers. Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match all the string:

```js
pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"
```

Proof:

```html
<form name="f"> 
 <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" title="Please enter avalid name" />
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: I get still - You can write only letters. error :(

Comment: I see, but i can't see where is my mistaked that leads to this error

Comment: Thanks for your reponse.I restarted the server and now it is working,,,I  accepted your answer.Btw what changes here the + sign at the end ? what is the difference when the user types something with + or without

Comment: @John87864 You must match the whole input text with the pattern. Else, it does not work.